# How to set default project page to dashboard in SonarQube 5.5?

Tags: sonarqube, dashboard, sonarqube-web

Today I upgraded our sonar instance from 4.5 to 5.5.

On 4.5 when you opened a project it opened a [dashboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLQr4.png), top three entries in the left menu being dashboards.

On 5.5 when you open the project you get to the [project home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/834oC.png), a page that didn't exist in 4.5.

If you want to see the dashboard you have to open the dashboard dropdown in the top menu and select the dashboard you're looking for.

I couldn't find any configurable setting to change the default project page, so the default page would be the first dashboard entry named "Dashboard".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one. The project home is the new, immutable front page for the project view.